# On running the Explore function for visualising mtcars dataset in R studio, it shows, could not find function, when it has been already installed

Tags: r, dplyr

This was the output that was shown on running the code-

library(explore)
Error in library(explore) : there is no package called ‘explore’

> install.packages(explore)
> Error in install.packages : object 'explore' not found

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote the package you're hoping to install.

```
install.packages("explore")
library(explore)
```